# Android divider in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm setting divider of childView. But when I'm expanding and see childRows divider's color changes in child and in parent rows. Why is it so?

My xml of expandableListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ExpandableListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:childDivider="@color/dark_orange"
android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator">
 </ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

change your ExpandableListView to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ExpandableListView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:dividerHeight="2dp"<!--===========> problem is here-->
  android:divider="@drawable/yellow"
  android:childDivider="@color/dark_orange"
  android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
  android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
  android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
/>
```

I think problem is at setting the height of the child divider. so please correct it.

Comment: It doesn`t help. It just sets height of devider to 2 dp.

Answer (score 0):

I've set divider colors through code like this:

```
int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; // red for the example 
lv.setChildDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors)); 
lv.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
```

Note this sets a divider at full color in the middle fading to nothing at bth edges, but it should convey the method for setting your ExpandableListView dividers in your code.  It would be just as easy to set the color to a single solid color.